# Ubuntu - saying your security settings have blocked an application from running with an out-of-date version of java

Tags: networking, ssh, java, google-chrome, security

I have this new problem since 2014 begin. I cant remotely login to this enterprise network
for giving them support. Its keep showing this new error.

How to fix it please?

[image]

EDIT:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please see my EDIT section nothing so special.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the last Update to `jdk 7u51`, in the default settings of java (High) is not allowing to run java untrusted apps. I could remember to run some apps with same high security some days ago but now those are getting blocked. Only applets having a certificate and proper permissions attribute can be run.

**How to run apps without certificate**

- Update your jdk, latest is available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- [**Never recommend, Do only if you trust the app**] Open Java Control Panel by running `javaws -viewer`, Keep your security settings to Medium, it will allow all applications to run except applications that request all permissions. So it is vulnerable, should you run a malicious application<sup>[[source]](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)</sup>

[image: screenshot of java control panel]

Comment: Just to help others in the future - to open the control panel easily you can type in **javaws -viewer**

Comment: The control panel for Oracle Java 8 now omits the 'medium' setting, but the 'high' setting combined with an exception appears to permit unsigned apps to run, albeit with a lot of security warnings (which should be heeded!).