# Chrome doesn't allow me to run Opera Mini simulator

Tags: 12.04, java, google-chrome

Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

[image: screenshot]

I'm using Chrome 32.

Answer (score 2):

Since the last Update to `jdk 7u51`, in the default settings of java is not allowing to run java un-trusted apps. Only applets having a certificate and proper permissions attribute can be run.

**Running app/website without certificate**

- Make sure you've the latest version. It is [jdk-7u51](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- Open Java Control Panel & Alter your security settings to Medium. It will allow all applications & java enabled services to run except applications that request all permissions.

  [image: Java Control Panel]

Note: Make sure you're doing this by acknowledging that the application can be trusted. Unless I would recommend not to alter any changes.

I also recommend you to have a read on [**How do I control when an untrusted applet or application runs in my web browser?**](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)

Hope this helps!

**Source:** [Ubuntu - saying your security settings have blocked an application from running with an out-of-date version of java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408646/ubuntu-saying-your-security-settings-have-blocked-an-application-from-running)